# error c3861: '_crt_va_end': identifier not found

Tags: c++

I've got

error C3861:'_crt_va_end':identifier not found

and also

IntelliSense: identifier "_crt_va_end": identifier not found

I have no clue what to do so I post my entire project and hope someone will help me.

This is my code:

```
#ifndef PRODUCT_H
#define PRODUCT_H

#include<string>
using namespace std;

class Product{
private:
    string name;
    string brand;
    int availability;
    static double totalSale;
public:
    Product(string = "", string = "", int = 0);
    virtual ~Product();
    Product & setName(string);
    Product & setBrand(string);
    Product & setAvailabilty(int);
    string getName() const;
    string getBrand() const;
    int getAvailability() const;
    static void addTotalSale(double);
    static double getTotalSale();
    virtual double calculatePayment(int) = 0;
    virtual double calculateTax(int) = 0;
    virtual double calculateCost(int) = 0;
};

#endif





#include"Product.h"

double Product::totalSale = 0;

Product::Product(string pName, string pBrand, int quantity){
    setName(pName);
    setBrand(pBrand);
    setAvailabilty(quantity);
}
Product::~Product(){
}
Product & Product::setName(string pName){
    name = pName;
    return *this;
}
Product & Product::setBrand(string pBrand){
    brand = pBrand;
    return *this;
}
Product & Product::setAvailabilty(int quantity){
    availability = quantity;
    return *this;
}
string Product::getName() const{
    return name;
}
string Product::getBrand() const{
    return brand;
}
int Product::getAvailability() const{
    return availability;
}
void Product::addTotalSale(double amount){
    totalSale += amount;
}
double Product::getTotalSale(){
    return totalSale;
}




#ifndef SMOKING_H
#define SMOKING_H

#include"Product.h"

class Smoking : public Product{
private:
    double price;
    const double taxPercentage;
public:
    Smoking(string = "", string = "", int = 0, double = 0, double = 0);
    ~Smoking();
    Smoking & setPrice(double);
    double getPrice() const;
    double getTaxPercentage() const;
    double calculatePayment(int) override;
    double calculateTax(int) override;
    double calculateCost(int) override;
};

#endif





#include"Smoking.h"


Smoking::Smoking(string pName, string pBrand, int quantity, double fPrice, double tax)
    : Product(pName, pBrand, quantity), taxPercentage(tax){
        setPrice(fPrice);
}
Smoking::~Smoking(){
}
Smoking & Smoking::setPrice(double fPrice){
    price = fPrice;
    return *this;
}
double Smoking::getPrice() const{
    return price;
}
double Smoking::getTaxPercentage() const{
    return taxPercentage;
}
double Smoking::calculatePayment(int quantity){
    return quantity * getPrice();
}
double Smoking::calculateTax(int quantity){
    return calculatePayment(quantity) * getTaxPercentage() / 100;
}
double Smoking::calculateCost(int quantity){
    Product::addTotalSale(calculatePayment(quantity));
    return calculatePayment(quantity) + calculateTax(quantity);
}




#ifndef FOOD_H
#define FOOD_H

#include"Product.h"


class Food : public Product{
private:
    double price;
    const double taxPercentage;
public:
    Food(string = "", string = "", int = 0, double = 0, double = 0);
    ~Food();
    Food & setPrice(double);
    double getPrice() const;
    double getTaxPercentage() const;
    double calculatePayment(int) override;
    double calculateTax(int) override;
    double calculateCost(int) override;
};

#endif






#include"Food.h"

Food::Food(string pName, string pBrand, int quantity, double fPrice, double tax)
    : Product(pName, pBrand, quantity), taxPercentage(tax){
        setPrice(fPrice);
}
Food::~Food(){
}
Food & Food::setPrice(double fPrice){
    price = fPrice;
    return *this;
}
double Food::getPrice() const{
    return price;
}
double Food::getTaxPercentage() const{
    return taxPercentage;
}
double Food::calculatePayment(int quantity){
    return quantity * getPrice();
}
double Food::calculateTax(int quantity){
    return calculatePayment(quantity) * getTaxPercentage() / 100;
}
double Food::calculateCost(int quantity){
    Product::addTotalSale(calculatePayment(quantity));
    return calculatePayment(quantity) + calculateTax(quantity);
}





#ifndef ALCOHOL_H
#define ALCOHOL_H

#include"Product.h"

class Alcohol : public Product{
private:
    double price;
    const double taxPercentage;
public:
    Alcohol(string = "", string = "", int = 0, double = 0, double = 0);
    ~Alcohol();
    Alcohol & setPrice(double);
    double getPrice() const;
    double getTaxPercentage() const;
    double calculatePayment(int) override;
    double calculateTax(int) override;
    double calculateCost(int) override;
};

#endif



#include"Alcohol.h"


Alcohol::Alcohol(string pName, string pBrand, int quantity, double fPrice, double tax)
    : Product(pName, pBrand, quantity), taxPercentage(tax){
        setPrice(fPrice);
}
Alcohol::~Alcohol(){
}
Alcohol & Alcohol::setPrice(double fPrice){
    price = fPrice;
    return *this;
}
double Alcohol::getPrice() const{
    return price;
}
double Alcohol::getTaxPercentage() const{
    return taxPercentage;
}
double Alcohol::calculatePayment(int quantity){
    return quantity * getPrice();
}
double Alcohol::calculateTax(int quantity){
    return calculatePayment(quantity) * getTaxPercentage() / 100;
}
double Alcohol::calculateCost(int quantity){
    Product::addTotalSale(calculatePayment(quantity));
    return calculatePayment(quantity) + calculateTax(quantity);
}



#include"Food.h"
#include"Smoking.h"
#include"Alcohol.h"

#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    vector<Product *> product;
    Smoking smoke("Cigarret","Winston",5,100,100);
    Alcohol alcohol("Cogniac","Ararat",10,200,50);
    Food food("Drinks","Water",20,1.25,1);
    product.push_back(&alcohol);
    product.push_back(&food);
    product.push_back(&smoke);
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < product.size(); ++i)
        cout << product[i]->getName() << endl << product[i]->getBrand() << endl
        << product[i]->getAvailability() << endl << product[i]->calculatePayment(1)
        << endl << product[i]->calculateTax(1) << endl << 
                product[i]->calculateCost(1) <<
        endl << endl << endl << endl;
    cout << Product::getTotalSale() << endl << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That compiler error must at least tell you which file it was in, and quite likely which line

Answer (score 0):

I have build your project in *Visual Studio 2013* completely with no file changed, and it does work! The putput of the main function are on the follow

```
Cogniac
Ararat
10
200
100
300

Drinks
Water
20
1.25
0.0125
1.2625

Cigarret
Winston
5
100
100
500

301.25
```

Does it the result that you want?
I guess that the problem of yours is the compiler, you may just clean the project and rebuild it.